# Graphql upload file shows as empty object

Tags: graphql, upload, apollo-angular

when I'm trying to upload file via Graphql mutation (`apollo-angular`) with parameter `$file: Upload!`, the variable value is shown as an `empty object` in developer tools:
[image: value of file variable is empty object]

But I'm checking the value of the variable right before the request and the value is correct, it is in fact a File, not an empty object.

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';

  this.apollo.mutate(
    {
      mutation: gql`
        ${uploadMutation}
      `,
      variables: {
        companyId,
        file <-- Here the value is correct, it is a File
      },
      context: {
        hasUpload: true,
        useMultipart: true
      }
    },
    'upload'
  );
```

Code is simplified for the sake of this example.

Is it just developer tools issue, am I doing something wrong or what is the problem please?

Comment: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec

Comment: Based on this, it looks like my implementation is correct, no? @xadm

Comment: not ... do you see FormData request, `operations` field and `file` nulled?

Comment: Did you figure it out yet?

Comment: I didn't so I completely reworked it and found out that there was a problem with FormData in the first place. If I remember correctly, when creating the project, some properties were causing a problem. I'm not sure, I don't have access to the repo so I can't refresh my memory, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You have to config the Apollo client with this:

```
import { createUploadLink } from 'apollo-upload-client'

const link = createUploadLink(/* Options */)
```

Resource: https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client/issues/89#issuecomment-384923295